# What are the crimes for which people become ghosts, and for how long do they stay so?

Tags: karma, sin, ghosts

What are the crimes for which people become ghosts, and for how long do they stay so? (I got this part [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14961/reasons-for-attaining-preta-janma-and-how-to-get-relieved)), but for how much *time* will they stay as ghosts? (references are better than personal opinions)?

I read a story in which the person steals some food for a family with which he doesn't have any relations and then since his intention was good, Indra himself came to take him to Swarga.

The main thing is that those reasons matter a lot...if someone steals something, then the rules are the same but in God's eye, I think there must be some sort of "if someone commits any of those crimes for "________" reasons," then it's ok and they don't become ghosts.

Is that the case?

Comment: Yes but it is half ..My ques is more then that it's not just about that link...when you read you will understand.. Also plz see that link I gave in ques you will see from where this ques raised.

Comment: Also when I heard garuda Purana it is said that only for starting 13 days people become pret and after you do last rituals person will be relieved , even if he do suicide or other crimes?

Comment: The final state of mind while death is decisive. If you mean "suicide" by "giving up life on own", then that doesn't always bring to the *bhuta-preta*. For example, some soldiers go suicidal during the war (see *Kamikaze* of Japan). Such actions may bring them to higher region, as they got killed during battle. Drona gave up his life in the middle of war with *Kriya yoga*, towards liberation. Bhishma gave up his life at certain auspicious period while praising lord Krishna, hence attained liberation. Those who suicide out of fear, may certainly carry fear & hence become ghosts beyond 13 days.

Comment: Very nice now this is exactly what answers my question. But can you please elaborate it more cases like I don't know I should write in this site or not but like rape cases (suicide) or killing of some dear person in front of a person's eyes in which he take revenge (killing).I don't want to close this ques before it provide me suitable answer.

Comment: Doesn't matter what the case (murder etc) is, only thing that matter is your mental state and thoughts at time of death. If your thoughts are focus on Lord on your death time then you won't get any neech yoni. What thoughts is in your mind at time of death, that is the key reason of next yoni. So on time of death, it is highly advisable that, one should maintain his/her focus only on Lord by leaving all worries of worldly things(family, money, fame ect). On time of death, one has to overcome from all good or bad incident and must have lost in his Aaradhya's thoughts only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for obtaining an existence among *bhuta-preta* is already discussed in my answer to:
[Reasons for attaining preta janma and how to get relieved](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14961/1049)

As also mentioned there, the amount of time one remains in this situation is not specified. As a rule of thumb, one goes in the upward regions if *Sattva* increases, one goes to lower regions if *Tamas* increases. One sticks in the same region, if *Rajas* is predominant. Hence if an entity has to come out of the ghost life then it requires *Sattva*, which is illuminating by nature.

---

Regarding "Suicide", it's English definition is "the act or an instance of taking one's own life voluntarily and intentionally". Now if this meaning has to be believed then "suicide" is not necessarily ghost creator in all the instances. For example, as I have discussed already in the comment to your Qn, Drona & Bhishma gave up their life voluntarily in the state of Yoga. They did not become ghosts. Refer [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16361/1049).

> BG 8.6 — Also [when] the body is left remembering this or that "Nature" at the end, O son of Kunti, [it] always approaches towards establishing those nature(s) only.

The time of the death is also important. You may further read [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19385/1049).

Comment: It's too complicated for me to understand. It's answers are so complicated. How lucky those people are who has chance to do Seva of Shiva..I would be happy if this chance I get even if I became ghost. May God lead to right path those people who are depressed and wanna suicide. And lead right path to them who are going to be the pain for other people. And God bless to those who care and do things for others happiness.