# If I pray to Ravana or some Devil ,then will Krishna steady my faith in him?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

In Bhagwat Gita Lord [says](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/7/21) :

> I am in everyone’s heart as the Supersoul. As soon as one desires to
>   worship some deity, I make his faith steady so that he can devote
>   himself to that particular deity.

Suppose I want to worship Ravana or Pret  or Pisach then will Krishna make my faith steady in those demonic forces ?

If yes then is there any morality innate to Lord Krishna?

I think there is no morality innate to Lord Krishna ( I don't want to hurt any sentiments. I have high regards for the Paramatma.) In order to clarify what I mean by that let us consider an example , suppose  I support and protect good people who pray me but I also support people who are rapists and murderers and thieves indirectly then am I a person of moral integrity? No.

Comment: BTW Ravana and devils are not a demi-god.

Comment: Well Ravana was not enemy to Krishna. He is a Rakshasa(from mother) and Brahmana (from father). So He is no devil. Do not put Ravana under category of Pisacha, Preta et cetera.

Comment: Ravana was an evil person as he disturbed the peace of Rishi and Munis. He also kidnapped another man's wife. There is no point in debating the goodness of Ravana. Anyways , who is the demi-god ? (According to me ,if I admire Pisacha or Chudail etc then they are my Gods)

Comment: Lord Krishna is neither moral nor immoral when functioning as a paramatma. He as a paramatma will just respond to the desire of a particular person. So, if you want to worship evil spirits or some god in heaven such as Indra, the Lord will enable you to develop faith according to your desire.

Comment: @AnuragSingh **Ravana was not enemy to Krishna** Not only Ravana but there is/was/will not any enemy of Krishna (Parbrahma). If any devil considers Lord as his enemy then Lord consider those devils as his devotee Because if one mades Lord his enemy then that person will keep thinking about Lord as enemy and whoever thinks about Lord is his Devotee. Doesn't matter you think of Lord with Love or with Hate, Lord will take that thinking as devotion of your.

Comment: @Rishabh Yes. Exactly. MaaPati is always compassionate to all. And this is also the reason why DevakiSunu killed the Rakshasas with His own hand to reach them Salvation.

Comment: Dheeraj You do not know anything about LankaaRaaja. We always see what is on an upper level. In this sense, even Hari stole the clothes of Gopikaas when they were bathing. Does it mean MadhuDweshi is a lust stricken God? No. Similarly, people think DashaVaktra is an evil, where in fact they know nothing of Him. They call Him Rakshasa, and do not even know that He was Brahma's grandson.

Comment: And worshipping evil spirits (why even call them evil), has only this drawback that after death you also have to become those spirits. But at the end whomever you worship you have to merge with Krishna only. And moreover, it is Bhaava(sentiment) which matters, if you worship spirits with evil mind, then evil may you become. If with a pure devotional heart, then divinity will dawn.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Yes you are right partially in your last 2 comments (as per me). Although Ravana was son of Branma But he follows rakshasa dharma in his life. Unlike Lord Brahma he was of rajasa pravriti instead of satvik pravriti. He mostly act like a selfish cruel rural instead of a sage. Hence he is both Brahana and rakshasa. But coz of his karma he is more famous coz of his rakshasa guna instead of brahmana guna. His cruelty becomes more popular than his veda adhyana.

Comment: @Rishabh Well Brahma is also RajoGunaPradhaana. In fact ChaturAasya has RajoGuna in preponderance, Kamalekshana has Sattva Guna, and KrittiVaasaa has TamoGuna inherent.

Comment: @AnuragSingh I am not agreed with you thought of rajasa guna of Brahma. Besides how you can compare leela (stole clothes) of Lord Krishna with sins of Ravana? Krishna was a pure soul And Ravana was Evil soul. He spread terror in all lokas. He followed Rakshasa dharma in his life. How in the world you can compare a cruel personality who is guided by only selfness with Lord Krishna who has no self thing in his life. Moreover most of the karma of Ravana was of tamksik also.

Comment: In Shaastras Brahma is said to Rule Rajo Guna. Vishnu rules Sattva and Shiva rules Tamas. And I did not compare NandaNandana with Raavana. I said people with less speculation look only on upper level and may not even hesitate saying that LakshmiPriya was lustful because He stole Gopikas' clothes when they were naked. Where in fact, it was a Leela of Sharngaayudha. Similarly people do speak Raavana is this that such, but do not know about him at all. In fact none of the Asuras were evil, it was indeed just their depiction. Even Suras do evil but this does not establish them being wrong.

Comment: where it has been stated ravana is a demigod !! it has been described about any of the demigods (whomever due to lack of knowledge people worship) for the fulfillment of the short term material desires.

Comment: if you pray to rapists and murderers and thieves indirectly, it makes you a person of prayer, it doesn't make you a person of morality. All Krishna would do is make your faith steady in that person, and if that person is bad, you'll also be bad faithfully. it won't make you good.

Comment: Yes Krishna will make one stead in that faith. Will make one born in Demons womb again and again.. till permenant andhamas is achieved by the soul, just like moksha there is opposite of moksha andhamas reference BG 16.19

Comment: where it has been stated ravana is a demigod !!

it has been described about any of the demigods (whomever due to lack of knowledge people worship) for the fulfillment of the short term material desires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 will Krishna make my faith steady in those demonic forces ?
```

**Yes**. The verse 7.21 is already listed in your Qn.
Under the mode of *tamas*, one prays to [possibly demonic] forces such as *bhuta-preta* or *pishAcha*:

> यजन्ते सात्त्विका देवान्यक्षरक्षांसि राजसाः। **प्रेतान्भूतगणांश्चान्ये** यजन्ते तामसा जनाः
>   BG 17.4 - Those with *sattva*, worship the *deva*-s; those having *rajas*, worship the *Yaksha* and *Raksha* (*rAkshasa*); Other people **possessed of *tamas*, worship ghosts and the spirits**

Based on entity being worshipped, a person is more likely to get such thoughts during death. In such case, one attains such worlds. Refer [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20378/1049).

```
If yes then is there any morality innate to Lord Krishna?
```

According to Krishna, whether one worships to good/bad/ugly -- whichever demigod -- is non-methodical. Though, it ultimately reaches to supreme One only.

> BG 9.23 - O son of Kunti, Even those who being devoted to other deities and endowed with faith, worship [them], they also worship Me alone, following the wrong method.

People make their choices of worship according to their nature. They are helpless under *Prakruti*.
Wise people avoid judging their faith or lack of faith.

Comment: So you agree that there is no innate morality in Supreme Lord ? Lord supports whatever faith I take. There will be no resistance from God on me making a evil choice.

Comment: @Dheeraj yes that's correct. God helps you to strengthen your liking of faith.

Comment: @dheerajverma Just one point adding on iammilind's comment. Even if God won't stop your faith that doesn't mean one should faith on Evils. Because if you will do that then you will get more far/away from moksha (final goal of human life).

Comment: @DheerajVerma in hinduism there is only cause and effect. The lord will not make you change the cause(your choice to worship demons, for example) and will not affect the effects that you will reap as a natural result.

Comment: @DheerajVerma there is innate morality in Krishna in the sense that good choices lead to good effects. The definition of good may however be different for different individuals.